# Express: How to implement the JSON API

Tags: json, express, json-api

I have a very basic express server which simply offers model-data via mongoose for webapps. So now since in my Framework (ember) the JSON-API is the new default adapter for requesting model-data, Im wondering how to implement a response for my route in a way which respects the JSON API specification.

My current route in express looks like that.

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  postModel.find({ //Mongoose functions
    _id: req.params.id
  }, function(err, doc) {
    res.json({ //returning the doc
      data: doc //within 'doc', the 'type'-key must be added
    });
  });

});
```

I have to include a key for the "type" in each responded object so the responding object will looks like that:

```
{
  data:{
    type:"post",
    id:"123",
    title:"test"
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know express. Your get call should be: "/[type]/[id]".
Example for your post model: get with /posts/123

And the returning object should look like this:
data:{
    type:"posts",
    id:"123", attributes: {title:"test"} 
  }
Like in the json-api spec: http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-objects

Comment: Yeah I know these rules. Because of express module/middleware concept, its correct to just use the  part `('/:id',` as long we include this file correctly in the main-file. Anyway my (main) problem is that I don't know how to add the type:"posts" key-value-pair into the `doc`-var which is the result from mongoose document request. Im wondering if there is a confortable way to finding records/document in mongodb with mongoose which already corresponds the jsonapi (with "type"-field etc)

Comment: oh sorry, didn't understand that right (as said, i don't know express/mongoose).
But maybe this github issue helps: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1867

Comment: Any new thoughts on this subject? There is this router helper: https://github.com/crimsonronin/express-json-api  but I'm not sure if it's actively developed. Maybe there are other solutions that are well backed?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better answer. My request handler in express:

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  Lookup.findById(req.params.id, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      res.send({
        error: err
      });
    } else {
      res.send(to_jsonapi(result, 'lookup'));
    }
  });
});
```

This calls a utility function which converts the mongoose result into a valid jsonapi result. You just need to call it with the result plus the 'type' value.

```
function to_jsonapi(result, type) {
  datajson = [];
  if (Array.isArray(result)) {
    result.forEach(function(item) {
      datajson.push({
        "type": type,
        "id": item._id,
        "attributes": item
      });
    });
  } else if (typeof result === "object") {
    // Happens when there is only one item
    datajson.push({
      "type": type,
      "id": result._id,
      "attributes": result
    });
  } else {
    datajson.push({
      "type": type
    });
  }
  return {
    "data": datajson
  };
}
```

This is not perfect yet but should get you down the road!

Comment: Thanks for that answer, have you found new information since? the json-api packages I've found haven't worked well.

Answer (score 0):

I am just running in to this same problem. There is an [ember-mongoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-mongoose) npm package but I have not used it yet. The way they solve the problem is actually back in the ember-data side by extending the DS.RESTAdapter. There they overwrite the findQuery function.

```
findQuery: function(store, type, query) {
    var data = { query: query };
    return this.ajax(this.buildURL(type.typeKey), 'POST', { data: data });
  }
```

This is not that elegant though since it requires a customization for every data type. You can see the example [here](https://github.com/kelonye/ember-mongoose/blob/master/lib/client/index.js).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **lean()**

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  postModel
    .find({_id: req.params.id})
    .lean()
    .then( docs => {
      _.each( docs, doc => {
        doc.type = "post";
      });
      res.json(data: docs);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing jsonapi on server side because it will be then automatically parsed by your Ember.js Data, then I would suggest to look at different Serializers which Ember.js provides. It will solve the problem. Because it's the job of the client to parse the data in whatever way Backend provides, not that we have to make our backend compatible with clients :)